# grunt-contrib-connect and access denied page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I'm a using grunt-contrib-connect (^0.8.x in package.json) for my angularJs project.

when I start the task `grunt connect` my shell says :

```
Running "connect:server" (connect) task
Waiting forever...
Started connect web server on http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

My browser open a new tab on `http://0.0.0.0:8000` and I have an access denied page

this is my code :

```
 connect: {
        server: {
            options: {
                keepalive: true,
                debug: true,
                open: {
                    target: 'http://localhost:8000'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm a mac user 10.9.5

My friend who use windows XP doesn't have the problem.

have you got an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `base` parameter on your server. Without it, connect doesn't know what directory its supposed to be serving files from.

```
connect: {
    server: {
        options: {
            keepalive: true,
            debug: true,
            base: "path/to/source",
            open: true
        }
    }
}
```